# How to add an top level menu item in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to add some menu in the top level area in odoo 10

before the setting menu

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a new menuitem tag without parent. Like:

```
<menuitem name="Custom Menu" id="custom_menu_without_parent"/>
```

And put some childs pointing to that menu, like:

```
<menuitem name="Custom Menu Group" id="custom_menu_group" parent="custom_menu_without_parent" sequence="1"/>
<menuitem name="Custom Menu Entry" id="custom_menu_entry" parent="custom_menu_group" action="custom_entry_action" sequence="2"/>
```